# Symbolic link for lampp isn't working 100%

Tags: 13.04, symbolic-link, xampp

Note: I'm a beginner in ubuntu
I've been trying for some time to set XAMPP up on my Ubuntu machine so I can develop my PHP projects. I found out that I can't directly modify the htdocs folder because it is located in a protected part of the system. Then I found out that creating a symbolic link of my /home/(user)/Projects inside my /opt/lampp/htdocs folder would solve it. It kinda did, but not totally. The symbolic link does work because lampp can access the files that are in /home/(user)/Projects but it won't read subfolders. I read something about having to change the permissions but I'd rather avoid it for security purposes. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: I'm no expert on apache, but I think a good solution to your problem would be to setup a virtual host that will point to your designated home subfolder as document root. This is done by editing the apache configuration files. Read the documentation on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ There are some examples in there.

Comment: I couldn't figure how to work this out by myself, I'm sorry, do you have any simpler solution? I wouldn't mind dabbling with permissions as long as it works

Comment: Warning: include(/layouts/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/valmir/Projects/project1/index.php on line 1  
  
   |   I get other three identical errors related to other files

Comment: Try adding your user to the same group the user running the apache process is. I think it is www-data but I'm not sure. This should give sufficient access rights to the apache process.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer, but this didn't fix it. My valmir user is now at www-data group but the error persists.

Comment: Problem fixed by myself, I tried to make a new symbolic link and now it worked, I think I was doing something wrong